# How to cancel the running task method without specify any code inside the task method in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
{
  Task myTask = Task.Run(() => method(), cancelTokenSource.Token);
  cancelTokenSource.cancel();
}

void method()
{
    //Without specify any code like 
    cancelTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

is there any alternate way to cancel the running task?

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Comment: Yes, end the whole application